# VB Calculation using the greater of 2 numbers from two textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a tool to calculate DOL Tax Title and Licensing Fees. I need help in figuring something out., I have 3 text boxes 1 for Purchase Price (PurAmount), another for Vehicle Value (VehicleVal) and lastly the Sales Tax (TaxRate).

I need to calculate Sales Tax but I want the calculation to automatically use the greater number input in the Purchase Price or Vehicle Value.

```
Else
    SalesTax.Value = (CDbl(PurAmount) * (Replace(TaxRate, "%", "") * 0.01))
End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags to your question. Tags are not a way to trick more people into seeing your question. They are a means for us to know what questions are relevant to us. Lying to people about whether your question is relevant to them is not the way to encourage people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
PP = InputBox("Enter Purchase Price")  'Entered 3000
VV = InputBox("Enter Vehicle Value")   'Entered 2500
TR = .10
Tax = WorksheetFunction.Max(PP,VV) * TR
?Tax
 300
```

I did the above in the Immediate Window of the VBE should work the same in your code.

HTH